# Tabris "Hello World" application not shown

Tags: eclipse, demo, servletexception

I am trying to follow the hello world tutorial at http://developer.eclipsesource.com/tabris/docs/gettingstarted-hello-world. I setup everything as explained but when I try to launch the browser 
**an Error 404 - Not Found is thrown.**

No context on this server matched or handled this request.

I am using the J2EE Preview server.

Any idea why this occurs or how to fix?

Comment: If I switch to the Apache Tomcat web server I got a ClassNotFoundException for  org.eclipse.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a bug which I recently fixed in the web.xml (see commit https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-sdk/commit/bf6400006768353a85b925a9239aceb82d190bcf).

The class org.eclipse.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener has moved to org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener (note the difference is "rap"). It's fixed in the next SDK but in your example you need to modify the listener-class property in the WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml file to "org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServletContextListener".

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks, I also had to change rwt servlet to org.eclipse.rap.rwt.engine.RWTServlet.